# Not able to get the iphone build version

Tags: ios, swift, iphone

I am trying to retrieve the iPhone operating system build version. I am not looking for build version for the app. I know how to get the current iOS version of the device. But I couldn't find any reference for build version in UIDevice documentation provided by Apple

```
  <key>iPhone11,6</key>
    <dict>
      <key>16F203</key> 
      <dict>
        <key>Restore</key>
        <dict>
          <key>BuildVersion</key>
          <string>16F203</string>
        </dict>
        ......
```

In the above XML, **16F203** is one of the build version. 
The above XML is extracted from the XML response from phobos.apple.com/version. 
Thanks in Advance

Comment: is that info.plist? Can you post some code?

Comment: Not it is not info.plist. I got this XML from phobos.apple.com/version. I need to parse this XML and search for available iOS version for the current device

Comment: `print(ProcessInfo().operatingSystemVersionString)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ObjC:

```
NSString *verStr = [[NSProcessInfo processInfo] operatingSystemVersionString];
NSLog(@"%@", verStr);
```

Swift:

```
let verStr = ProcessInfo().operatingSystemVersionString
print("\(verStr)")
```

Output:
Version 12.3.1 (Build **16F203**)